# Process flow to trigger notification when user first logs in to community?

Tags: process-builder, formula-field

I'm trying to create a trigger from a process builder flow which creates a push notification when the user first logs in to the community.

I start with the User object - when a record is created or edited. I then use a formula field which checks if the User LastLoginDate is changed and it was blank before.

Unfortunately with no luck - anyone came across this before?

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you look at OOTB functionality - [Login Flows](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_login_flow.htm&type=5) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. Create a custom field on User object "hasLoggedIn" (checkbox)
2. Set this to TRUE for all existing community users
3. Set this condition on your Process node for the notification
   [image]
4. Additional to the notification, add an update action to set the hasLoggedIn checkbox to true